How can I solve N+1 problem double prefetch_related using order_by in Django?
In models.py the simple structure is...
Model A(parent of B) <- Model B(parent of C) <- Model C

And in views.py, I want to use both prefetch_related in B,C and order_by in b.
a_obj = A.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch("b__c", queryset=B.objects.all().order_by("-order")))

but in serializers.py, I cannot access to c's data.
def get_data(self, group):
   for b in group.b.all():
      print(b.c.all())  # ===> result: queryset [B object(pk)]

And I also tried another way in views.py and serializers.py
# views.py
a_obj = A.objects.prefetch_related("b__c")

# serializers.py
def get_data(self, group):
   for b in group.b.all().order_by("-order"):
      print(b.c.all())  # ===> N+1 query occurred

But I have N+1 problem.
What should I do?

If you don't want to use a "global" ordering, you can work with a cascading Prefetch:
a_obj = A.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('b', queryset=B.objects.prefetch_related('c').order_by('-order'))
)

It's very simple. Editing in models.py that needs ordering.
And I deleted all of my codes in views.py and serializers.py
class B(models.Model):
   ...
   class Meta:
      ordering=['-order']

